# Obtain List of Pipelines/Datasets using Web Service - Failure

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm attempting to use the following to obtain a list of pipelines using an activity in ADF.

GET "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories//pipelines?api-version=2018-06-01"

I've setup a web activity to do this and have overcome the authorisation issues, however the JSON being returned doesn't seem to contain any "values" for the pipelines (or datasets if I choose to do so that way).

This is my output in ADF:

```
{
"value": [],
"ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "x-ms-correlation-request-id": "3760f8b9-498c-464b-8f61-1ccaa004ad7d",
    "x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads": "11998",
    "x-ms-request-id": "3760f8b9-498c-464b-8f61-1ccaa004ad7d",
    "x-ms-routing-request-id": "UKSOUTH:20220519T132708Z:3760f8b9-498c-464b-8f61-1ccaa004ad7d",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Date": "Thu, 19 May 2022 13:27:07 GMT",
    "Server": "Kestrel",
    "Content-Length": "17",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Expires": "-1"
},
"effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (UK South)",
"executionDuration": 0,
"durationInQueue": {
    "integrationRuntimeQueue": 1
},
"billingReference": {
    "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
    "billableDuration": [
        {
            "meterType": "ManagedVNetIR",
            "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
            "unit": "Hours"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Any assistance as to why its not returning anything would be fantastic, I'm currently using GIT and branches also so unsure if that would be having an impact.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in my environment and got the same error :

[image: Ref1]

I solved this error by adding a ***Manage identity*** as a ***contributor***.
Go to ***Azure Portal*** ->***Resource group*** -> ***Access Control (IAM)*** -> **Add Role assignment**.

[image: Ref2]

**Syntax:**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines/{pipelineName}?api-version=2018-06-01
```

[image: Ref3]

Adding the roles sometimes takes more time to refresh. So make sure to ***refresh*** the ***pipeline***.

[image: Ref3]

[image: Ref4]

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/get#code-try-0

Comment: Hey @Lynchie, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot.  [Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers "https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers")